# Docker not releasing ports

Tags: docker, boot2docker

*(On a Mac, Boot2Docker, docker v 1.1.1)*

Having trouble where Docker will not release the ports that it uses when assigning host ports.  For instance, I start 3 containers with the same image.  My `docker ps` returns the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
9875e2d28c3b        49ffc1050348        /sbin/my_init       19 hours ago        Up 1 seconds        0.0.0.0:49169->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49170->3306/tcp   boring_goldstine
f0a40c3bb4a1        49ffc1050348        /sbin/my_init       19 hours ago        Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:49167->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49168->3306/tcp   sleepy_wright
0fb913db3528        49ffc1050348        /sbin/my_init       19 hours ago        Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:49165->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49166->3306/tcp   agitated_jones
```

Scrolling over to ports you'll see that 49170 is the last allocated port.

If I stop and rm those containers and run another, Docker used to use the lowest available port.  However now the number just keeps increasing:

```
docker run -P -d 49ffc1050348

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
82fdf0e54846        49ffc1050348        /sbin/my_init       19 hours ago        Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:49171->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49172->3306/tcp   high_euclid
```

How do I get it to reuse the old ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [portmapper logic changed](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/commit/f387cc1205b79ffbe30b28f5df13da034d8221fd) in version 1.1.0. The logic is now written to increase until 65535, until it resets to `BeginPortRange` which is 49153.

You can use `docker run -p <host port>:<container port>` to map a host port to a container port.

Comment: Thanks Ben - Interesting.. I wonder why.  It was nice to rely on the fact that if I had no other containers running I would know their ports.  Bit of a pain for something like Boot2Docker where you have to manually expose ports.

Comment: At least `-p` should help with that since you can specify the port mapping